# Angular's directives as web components - why require up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently been making an effort to switch my directives (which often use linking functions) to be "web components" by moving the functionality from the link function into a controller (which is then exposed to other directives).

I often need components that are within the current one. In other words if component A is composed of B and C, it often needs B and C's API's so that it can function. Angular does not allow requiring components that are below in the DOM hierarchy (I believe). I find myself using an event scheme where after B and C activate they $emit an event and pass themselves as the argument. Then, A handles these events, grabs a reference of B and C then stops the propagation of the two events.

Upon thinking about this it seems backward. To me, a component should have the ability to reference the components it is composed of. Shouldn't the directives be linked bottom to top as opposed to top down? I mean, if a component is supposed to be a self contained black box that exposes an API to the world around it, it shouldn't be requiring components that are outside of itself. That destroys the separation between components and seems to couple them. However, requiring things inside of itself seems like a must...

Basically, I am asking two questions:
1) What is the logic behind requiring from outside (and not requiring from inside) other than "That is how Angular was originally built"?
2) Is the scheme that I am using ($emitting events on directive activation) a good one or is there a better way of grabbing directives from the inside?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you illustrate with a code example?

Comment: I feel like you might be looking at this in the wrong way.  The child objects always require their parents.  The parent should be exposing API functions that the child can leverage, rather than the child exposing an API to the parent.  The parent should be able to continue to function, even if the child did not exist.  This mirrors the way the DOM behaves;  a `<div>` can be rendered even if it doesn't have a child element, for example.

Comment: using `require` on child directives gives you a way to have the child directive need it's parent in order to function.  instead of `A` waiting to be told that it can do something, `B` can actually directly call `A.doSomething()`.  if `A` and `B` are using the same data, then use two way bound properties or `ng-model`, just as if `B` were the only directive on the page.

Comment: @ShaunScovil edited OP to add plunkr

Comment: @ShaunScovil nvm don't understand SO rules regarding plunkr's. Here is the link: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/esF2Yjl6T45wTmD86bde?p=preview

Comment: @Claies I a disagreeing with you. I think good components should never need their parents. They should need their children. If they need their parents then they are not a component in the sense that you can never move them somewhere else where the parent does not exist. A component should be self-contained. You can move it anywhere and it will do its thing. This way you can have several components (parents) that all use a child component as one of their building blocks.

Comment: yes, perhaps, but unfortunately that's not how angular 1.x is designed.  Angular 2 is a complete rewrite, in an attempt to leverage a design more closely related to the "component" aspect you are describing.  In angular 1.x, variables flow downward, but functions flow upward.  It's a limitation in the framework, but if you design your directives to make use of the isolate scope, you can, in many cases, create directives where `A` and `B` have no connection other than hierarchy.

Comment: for instance, in your example, there is no need for the child or parent directives to have a relationship;  using `ng-model` on the inner directive's template would allow two way binding of the variable, without any need to "activate" anything.

Comment: @Claies can you expand on "variables flow downward while functions flow upward", what do you mean by that? Thanks, I really appreciate the responses.

Comment: What I meant, basically, is that changes to variables on the `$scope` echo downward through all the child scopes through two way binding, and into directives through isolate scope definitions.  Functions, on the other hand, work the opposite;  A child can call functions on it's own scope and any parent scopes that are reachable, but cannot call functions in the children.

Comment: effectively, this creates a circular process;  child functions can call functions on the scopes above them, changing variables, whose changes echo back downward.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example violates the principle of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#General_definition):

> Example violates encapsulation principle

```
angular.module('app').controller('coolTextBoxCtrl', coolTextBoxCtrl)
function coolTextBoxCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.enabled = true;
    vm.model = '';

    activate();

    function activate() {
        console.log('publishing $scope');
        $scope.$emit('coolTextBoxActivated', vm);
    }
}
```

By publishing the **isolate scope** to the world to use, this example violates [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#General_definition) which is one of the four fundamental principles of object-oriented programming. Encapsulation is used **to hide the values or state of a structured data object** inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#General_definition)</sup>

A better approach is to use `bind-to-controller`.

```
angular.module('app').directive('coolTextBox', coolTextBox)
function coolTextBox() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'coolTextBoxCtrl as ctbc',
        template: '<input ng-model="ctbc.model">'+
                  '<p ng-style="{\'font-weight\': '+
                        'ctbc.enabled?\'bold\':\'\'}">'+
                  'scope-{{$id}}</p>'+
                  '{{ctbc}}'+
                  '<hr>',
        scope: {
            model: '=cbtModel',
            enabled: '=enabled'
        },
        bindToController: true
    }
}
```

Then expose public variables using attributes.

```
    <cool-text-box
       enabled="cfc.ctbc.enabled"
       cbt-model="cfc.ctbc.model"
    ></cool-text-box>
```

For more information on `bindToController`, see [AngularJS $compile Service Reference -- Comprehensive Directive API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

The [Updated DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lc3ErwJmOfPBBkIk2gHA?p=preview).